# What data type is used for saving lists in sqlite3 using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sqlite

As long as I know, there are only five data types that can be set to columns in a sqlite3 table. They are:

- `null` means no data.
- `integer` means a whole number.
- `real` means a float.
- `text` means any string.
- `blob` a binary data field in which you can store files, documents, images.

But currently, I have a list called `self. inventory` in my code, that gets items added into it occasionally when users' do something specific. That is not the issue. My problem is that what data type should I assign to the list that I want to store in the table? Or is there any other method I can use to store the values of the table into the db. Currently, here is my connection, cursor and table execution:

```py
connection = sqlite3.connect('db_of_game.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(
    'CREATE TABLE user_data(user_name text primary key, money integer, inventory <What data type to use here?>, deposited integer, allowed_deposit integer)'
    )

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: You could join the list items into a comma separated string (`"item1,item2,item3"`) and use the `text` type, then use `.split(",")` to get the list back when reading from the database.

Comment: Do I create a variable containing the comma separated string and add it into the table? Is it the best approach? How do I bring it back into the list when I want?

Comment: Yes, it would be a good idea to create a variable. This is probably the best approach, and certainly the simplest. To bring it back to a list, use `list.split(",")`. This will turn the comma separated string into a python list.

Comment: Never store comma separated strings in a table. read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: So what am I supposed to do? @forpas

Comment: Create another table with 2 columns: the 1st will reference the primary key of user_data and the 2nd for each item. So in that table you will have for each user as many rows as the user's items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each item can only belong to a single user, you'd use a one-to-many pattern. Many items, one user. Items have their own table and they refer to their user.

```
create items (
  id integer primary key,
  name text not null,
  user_name text not null references user_data(user_name)
)
```

(Note: Using a username as a primary key is to be avoided. Usernames change. Primary keys cannot change. They also require more storage and comparison time. Instead, use a simple integer. [In SQLite `integer primary key` works](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).)

Then to get all a user's items...

```
select items.name
from items
where user_name = ?
```

If each item can belong to many users, that is a many-to-many relationship and you need a join table to link users to items.

```
create items (
  id integer primary key,
  name text not null
)

create inventory (
  item_id integer not null references items(id),
  user_name text not null references user_data(user_name)
)
```

And to get a user's inventory you check inventory to get the item IDs and join with items to get the item name.

```
select items.name
from items
join inventory on items.id = inventory.item_id
where inventory.user_name = ?
```

This might seem convoluted, but this is how a *relational* database works. By setting up relationships between items. It takes a bit to wrap your head around, but it's worth it. It makes searching very fast. If you used a comma separated list and want to find the users with a certain item, you need to look at every user and parse their list. Now you just query the items table. If `items.name` is [indexed](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-indexes.htm) it will not have to search the whole table.

```
select *
from items
where item.name like ?
```

For more...

- [W3Schools - SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)
- [Visual representation of SQL joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)
- [TutorialsPoint - Using Joins](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm)
- [TutorialsPoint - Indexes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-indexes.htm)